# PHP and MYSQLI looping through months

Tags: php, json, mysqli

i am trying to retrieve Data for each month(01,02,03 etc.) but i don't know how to make a loop for it. Right now i have this for every month! (if've skipped out the other months so you don't have to see all of them).

```
 $queryJanuary = "SELECT count(*) AS num FROM unique_ip WHERE datum BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31'";
 $queryFebruari = "SELECT count(*) AS num FROM unique_ip WHERE datum BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-28'";


     if ($January = $Connection->query($queryJanuary)) {
          $Februari  = $Connection->query($queryFebruari);

            $rowJanuari = mysqli_fetch_assoc($January);
            $rowFebruari  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Februari);

            $january   = $rowJanuari['num'];
            $februari  = $rowFebruari['num'];

     }else {
         die();
           }

      $data = array($january, $februari);

     echo json_encode($data);
```

Database scheme:

1. IP UNSIGNED INT - PK
2. Datum Date NOT NULL
3. Telling INT NOT NULL - Default 1

   - datum means date
   - Telling means Counting

Also, Is it handy or atleast good practice to make the query's into prepared statements? this code will only be available on a private page that only I and other admins can reach.

Comment: show your table structure

Comment: @SunilPachlangia i added it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not really know what you are intent on doing, but just Try this for your SQL:

```
$queryJanuary    = "SELECT count(datum) AS num FROM unique_ip WHERE (datum>='2016-01-01' AND datum<='2016-01-31')";
$queryFebruari   = "SELECT count(datum) AS num FROM unique_ip WHERE (datum>='2016-02-01' AND datum<='2016-02-28')";

$data            = array(); //INITIALIZE DATA TO AN EMPTY ARRAY...
try{
    $January     = $Connection->query($queryJanuary);
    $Februari    = $Connection->query($queryFebruari);

    $rowJanuari  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($January);
    $rowFebruari = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Februari);

    $january     = $rowJanuari['num'];
    $februari    = $rowFebruari['num'];
    $data        = array($january, $februari);
}catch(Exception $e){
    //HANDLE YOUR EXCEPTION HERE...
    die();
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

You could as well do all these in one SQL Statement like so:

```
$queryAll       = "SELECT COUNT(datum) AS countJan,
                   (SELECT COUNT(datum) FROM unique_ip WHERE (datum>='2016-02-01' AND datum<='2016-02-28')) AS countFeb  
                   FROM unique_ip AS af WHERE (datum>='2016-01-01' AND datum<='2016-01-31')";
$data            = array(); //INITIALIZE $data TO AN EMPTY ARRAY...
$rowAll          = array(); //INITIALIZE $rowAll TO AN EMPTY ARRAY...

try{
    $query       = $Connection->query($queryAll);
    $rowAll      = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $january     = $rowAll['countJan'];
    $februari    = $rowAll['countFeb'];
    $data        = array($january, $februari);
    // BUT YOU DON NOT NEED TO PUSH $january & $februari INTO THE $data ARRAY 
    // BECAUSE YOU HAVE THOSE VALUES ALREADY INSIDE THE $rowAll VARIABLE 
    // WHICH SHOULD CONTAIN THESE KEYS: "countJan" & "countFeb"
}catch(Exception $e){
    //HANDLE YOUR EXCEPTION HERE...
    die();
}

//DUMP THE VALUES TO SEE IF THEY ARE WHAT YOU EXPECTED 
var_dump($data);
var_dump(rowAll);
```

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the amount my site is visited for every month. The database is filled with unique ip adresses with the Date of visit attached to them. I am trying to count the total amount of unique ip's per month and add them into an array

Comment: After some testing and trying out, i prefer your method! it is easier to work with in my eyes and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query.This will help you to take all month count in single query.

```
$queryallmonth = "SELECT MONTHNAME(datum) Month,COUNT(ip) num FROM unique_ip GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%Y%m')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use query:

```
SELECT count(*) AS num, EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM datum) as yearmonth  FROM unique_ip WHERE datum BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-05-02' GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM datum) DESC";
```

This SQL will give you the month wise count..

Comment: Thank you, do you also know the best way to put the output in an array?

Comment: Loop through the results and take yearmon as the index of the array and assign the count as value of array